# A simple implementation of a RecyclerView Listener

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I want the app to open a page when the user taps on an item and pass some extra information to that intent. That's it. I tried about 7 - 10 onclickListener types but I didn't solve anything. I am posting my adapter class with the latest implementation ( that doesn't work ). Json works and the Recyclerview loads data and images from url with no problems.

```
package byDragosT.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecipeApiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeApiAdapter.RecipeViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<RecipeItem> recipeItems;
    private Context context;

    public RecipeApiAdapter(ArrayList<RecipeItem> recipeItems, Context context){
        this.recipeItems = recipeItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override    //// Mare grija ce layout pui aici - sfat pentru viitor - mi-a luat 4 ore sa gasesc eroarea
    public RecipeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recipe_item_in_recyclerview_api, parent, false);
        return new RecipeViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecipeViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final RecipeItem recipeItem = recipeItems.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(recipeItem.getMnameRecipe());
        holder.description.setText(recipeItem.getMdescribeRecipe());

        Picasso.get().load(recipeItem.getItemPictureUrl())
                .into(holder.jpegRecipe);
        System.out.println("image with title: " + holder.title.getText() + "was added in theory");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recipeItems.size();
    }

    public static class RecipeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ImageView jpegRecipe;
        public TextView title;
        public TextView description;
        public RelativeLayout containerView;
        public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    RecipeViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            jpegRecipe = view.findViewById(R.id.picture);
            title = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_name);
            description = view.findViewById(R.id.ingredients_list);
            containerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_item_container); // vezi aici
            mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int itemPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(v);
            RecipeItem current = recipeItems.get(itemPosition);
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RecipeDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", current.getMnameRecipe());
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **view.setOnClickListener(this);**
 `RecipeViewHolder(View view){
  super(view);
  view.setOnClickListener(this);
  .....
}`

Comment: I used the implementation specified and I can click on the recyclerview now. I have another issue in onClick at line 'RecipeItem current = (RecipeItem) mRecyclerView.getTag();' - i get the dreaded Null Object Reference: _Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.getTag()' on a null object reference_.  The recyclerview shows photos and text so it is not null.